# Is there a difference in functionality when you use an intermediate variable during assignment?

Tags: java, variables

I'm having trouble understanding what makes method `A` different from method `B`.

```
public class ListNode {
    public String data;
    public ListNode next;
    public ListNode(String data, ListNode next) {
        this.data = data;
        this.next = next;
    }
}
public void A(ListNode list, String name) {
    ListNode asdf = new ListNode("hello", list);
    list = asdf;
}
public void B(ListNode list, String name) {
    list = new ListNode("hello", list);
}
```

Comment: ListNode and LIstNode are not the same Data type (unless that is a typo in which case doesn't even matter... they are different method names)

Comment: No difference -- they're both equivalent nonsense.

Comment: I looked at the `javap -c` output and was slightly surprised that the two methods do actually produce different output. The second really does use `asdf`; it stores the `new ListNode(...)`'s reference in `astore_3`, then immediately loads `astore_3` and stores that back in `astore_1`.  I would have thought that javac would be more clever, to save on the local frame's size.

Comment: @yshavit - javac doesn't optimize, to speak of.  It leaves that up to the JITC.

Comment: @HotLicks I realize it doesn't do most optimizations, but this is one I thought it wouldn't. Though as I thought about it more, it makes sense that it would. It does mean that with another arg, the `asdf` store would go from `astore_3` to `astore 4`, which costs an extra byte (a whole extra byte!). But that cost probably isn't worth the cost of duplicating the code to recognized unneeded vars, which the JIT would want to do anyway. Similarly, it means the method's frame would be bigger than it needs to be in interpreted mode, but that's also not worth the duplicated code.

Comment: @user3580294 It'll only inline `final` fields if they're compile-time constants, which must be any of the primitives or `java.lang.String`. If you try it above with `final ListNode asdf...` above, you'll see it doesn't inline it. So the issue isn't finality, but constant-ness (which effectively final doesn't affect).

Comment: @yshavit Ahh, you're right. My mistake.

Answer (score 2):

No difference (functionally speaking).

Note that re-binding a method parameter is confusing because parameters in Java are passed by value, so when the method ends, `list` will be the same value as before the method call, no matter if you re-bind inside the method. This means your newly created `ListNode` object will have no strong reference and will be eventually garbage-collected.

For example:

```
final ListNode a = new ListNode("pre-call", list);
A(a, "Some name");
System.out.println(a.data);  // Here it will print "pre-call" and not "hello"
```

Also it is usually considered a bad practice to re-bind parameters (kind of same as reusing variables). To avoid such mistakes I always declare method parameters as `final`.

Comment: Your point is right, and I was going to make a similar comment, but "`list` will be the same value as before the method call" is a bit misleading.  `list` is a variable, and doesn't mean anything outside of the method.  When you call `A` or `B` you pass it some `ListNode` x, and the *value* of `list` is initially x.  Then the method, without modifying the object x, assigns a different value to the variable `list`.  The point is the ListNode that is passed to `A` or `B` is never modified.

Comment: Yes you're right, probably confusing, I will make an example, thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 1):

The only difference is the readability of the two methods. Rest both the methods are doing the same thing

Answer (score 1):

In method A the first reference is asdf for newly created ListNode object. this ' list = asdf' makes list as another reference to same ListNode object. Thus in method A there are two references for same object.
 And the method B also does the same thing ie creates a new ListNode but this time using list as only reference.

Both methods achieve same thing but method A creates two references and assigns object to list indirectly while B on other hand directly uses list as a reference.